# listing files in a folder using C in Windows

Tags: c, visual-studio

I want to list the files in this folder "C:\home\WORK\Desktop\Communication". There are ten files in this folder. My code  has no error but it's not printing anything. What is my mistake ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  char path[]="C:\\home\\WORK\\Desktop\\Communication";
  strcat_s(path,sizeof(path),"\\*");

  WIN32_FIND_DATA fdata;
  HANDLE hFind =INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  int numberOfFiles=0;
  char *files[10];

 hFind = FindFirstFile(path,&fdata);

 while((FindNextFile(hFind,&fdata))!=0)
   {
     files[numberOfFiles]=fdata.cFileName;
     numberOfFiles++;
     printf("%s\n",files[numberOfFiles]);

   }

   FindClose(hFind);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

1. `strcat_s` can't append `"\\*"` to your `path` char array. The buffer only has enough room for storing the string literal.
2. I'm uncomfortable with letting you declare a buffer `files` that has only enough memory to fit all the file names. What happens if you add one more file? Then the buffer is overrun. However, it will still technically work in this scenario.
3. This line `printf("%s\n",files[numberOfFiles]);` is undefined behavior. You incremented `numberOfFiles` to a location in the array that has not been initialized, so it's not going to print the file name.
4. When you call `FindClose`, you invalidate all of those pointers that you stored in `files`. You can no longer use them. You need to copy the string to a new buffer.

---

The following code works.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char path[] = "C:\\home\\WORK\\Desktop\\Communication\\*.*";
    //strcat_s(path,sizeof(path),"\\*");

    WIN32_FIND_DATA fdata;
    HANDLE hFind =INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    int numberOfFiles=0;
    char* files[10]; /* you may want to expand this buffer */

    hFind = FindFirstFile(path,&fdata);

    while((FindNextFile(hFind,&fdata))!=0)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(fdata.cFileName);
        files[numberOfFiles] = malloc(len + 1 * sizeof*files); // len + 1 for null-terminator
        strcpy_s(files[numberOfFiles], len, fdata.cFileName);

        printf("%s\n",files[numberOfFiles]);
        numberOfFiles++; /* increment this AFTER you print files[numberOfFiles] */
    }

    FindClose(hFind);

    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(file)/sizeof(*file)); ++i) {
        free(file[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems, you should move

```
numberOfFiles++
```

past

```
printf("%s\n",files[numberOfFiles]);
```

Or

```
while((FindNextFile(hFind,&fdata))!=0)
{
    files[numberOfFiles]=fdata.cFileName;
    printf("%s\n", files[numberOfFiles++]);
}
```

Which is same as

```
while((FindNextFile(hFind,&fdata))!=0)
{
    printf("%s\n", files[numberOfFiles++] = fdata.cFileName);
}
```

I don't know WinAPI well, but I feel, that all `files` will contain invalid pointers after `FindClose(hFind)` as well as all elements of `files` will point to `*(fdata.cFileName)` which will be released in `FindClose(hFind)`. In other words, as I understand this, you should *copy* (or *duplicate*) `fdata.cFileName` into `files[i]` on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Clear `fdata` struct after declaring it:

```
memset( &fdata, 0, sizeof fdata )
```