# How to count the number of element in folder in C on Windows

Tags: c, directory

I am trying to find a way to count the number of element in a folder or access the number in the left bottom of a folder, indicating the number of element. [Screenshot of a program folder, with an arrow indicating the element number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01jWG.png)

I searched on the internet, but nothing seems to indicate how to do it. If anyone has the answer, please help.

Comment: use SO search option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program is aimed to run on windows only, you can use the following functions:

`FindFirstFileW` to start a directory scan and get a handle.
(See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew)

Then, using the given handle, call `FindNextFileW` (in a loop) to get the next entries.
(See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew).

Finally call `FindClose` to end the scan, and close the handle.

As mentioned by @yvw, you can see a full example of listing folder using Windows API at [listing files in a folder using C in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799170/listing-files-in-a-folder-using-c-in-windows)

Comment: Just to make sure, does it work in C, 'cause I keep seeing C++ everywhere ?

Comment: Yes, it works on C.
Also the answer at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799170/listing-files-in-a-folder-using-c-in-windows are written at C

Comment: Can I use the relative path or do I have to use the absolute path ?

Comment: Thanks to the link, i made a modification that gave the number of files and the program already gave the names of the elements but I don't know why, but there is always, no matter which directory, a "..." and that makes a +1 element which false the result. Here is the code. it should work for anyone without change the path.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{char path[] = ".\\*.*";WIN32_FIND_DATA fdata;HANDLE hFind =INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;int numberOfFiles=0;char* file[20];hFind = FindFirstFile(path,&fdata);
while((FindNextFile(hFind,&fdata))!=0)
{size_t len=strlen(fdata.cFileName);file[numberOfFiles]=malloc(len+1*sizeof*file);strcpy(file[numberOfFiles],fdata.cFileName);printf("%s\n",file[numberOfFiles]);numberOfFiles++;}
FindClose(hFind);
printf("%d", numberOfFiles);
for(int i = 0;i<(sizeof(file)/sizeof(*file)); ++i){free(file[i]);}
return 0;
}`

Comment: usually every folder has a '.' and '..' entries. this is valid. and you should skip these results when counting the entries.

Comment: Why is only one relative path and not absolute ? And is there a way to remove these dots ?

Comment: You can use also relative path. note the path is relative to your working directory (not to the executable path. I think there is no way to skip the '..' entry. you should skip it at your code.

Answer (score 0):

right click and highlight the ones you want to count